# Android - Place fragment over ImageView PROGRAMMATICALLY (NO XML)

Tags: java, android, background, imageview

I have to add a fragment over an Imageview, but my ImageView goes on top and covers the other views. All this is done in a RelativeLayout.

things must be done dynamically (no xml). I want that my activity has an image, which can be set DYNAMICALLY, and my fragment (added dynamically) should have transparent background, and if this is not true, i can set it to transparent at run time.

This is the code to create the image:

```
ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
img.setImageResource(imgID);
img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getRootView()).addView(img);
```

As you can see, the image works as background, i'm using a ImageView for its scaleType.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

solved, i added the image to the wrong container.

The function below, however, has been pretty useful. It has been taken from an other answer, and lets a view to get on the back of all the others.

```
public static void sendViewToBack(View child) {

            final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)child.getParent();

            if (parent!=null) {

                parent.removeView(child);
                parent.addView(child, 0);
            }
        }
```